# .exe file wont open after downloading through check update function

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

first post here but I have used quite a few articles from this site and I'm hoping someone can help. I'm working on a project for a tool everyone will use at my job.

```
        If My.Settings.Version >= Newestversion Then
        MsgBox("No Update Available!")
    ElseIf My.Settings.Version < Newestversion Then
        MsgBox("An update is available" & vbNewLine & "Update Now?", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel)
        If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            'Download Exe'
            If System.IO.File.Exists(("C:\Program Files (x86)\iSolved\iSolved Tech Tool\iSolvedTech.exe")) Then
                System.IO.File.Delete("C:\Program Files (x86)\iSolved\iSolved Tech Tool\iSolvedTech.exe")
                My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxn1ropdn101qa3/iSolvedTech.exe?dl=1", IO.Path.Combine("C:\Program Files (x86)\iSolved\iSolved Tech Tool", SaveExe))
            ElseIf System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Program Files (x86)\iSolved\iSolved Tech Tool\iSolvedTech.exe") = False Then
                My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxn1ropdn101qa3/iSolvedTech.exe?dl=1", IO.Path.Combine("C:\Program Files (x86)\iSolved\iSolved Tech Tool", SaveExe))
```

The code downloads the .exe file without any issues but when I try to launch the program from the downloaded .exe I get following error:

[image]

I have searched for hours on end trying to find out why it won't download the file correctly. Even tried using an embedded webbrowser on the form but that wont save the file to where it needs to go to restart itself. Any help is certainly appreciated. 
Another thing I noticed while writing this topic is that even if there is "No Update Available" when hitting okay on MsgBox("No Update Available")  the elseif statement still takes affect and downloads the files anyway. Am I missing something there? Is there a way to differentiate the two message boxes from eachother?

Comment: After some further troubleshooting I have found that it is not actually downloading the file. The placeholder for the .exe seems to be there but the file size is 0kb. Is there a way to elevate just this code to run higher to get full control over the file directory??

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to figure this out awhile back, just forgot about this question here.

The reason it was only downloading a placeholder was due to not having the `FileSystem.WriteAllBytes` method in the update function. I found this page [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) about that method on the Microsoft docs site. Hopefully this post will help another amateur like myself